# Getting rid of double green lines in blog posts

Tags: hyperlink, blogs

I have a blog on Blogger, and sometimes, I notice that double green lines are automatically added below certain words, which will display an ad if you hover over it (see picture below). Is there a way I could permanently make these lines not show up (e.g. by adding code to the Blogger template)? I just noticed them being added to some of my posts recently, and I want them to go away forever.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most probably a browser plugin/gadget that is inserting these links, not Blogger. Disable, or better, uninstall the TextEnhance plugin/gadget .

See: http://wafflesatnoon.com/2011/10/05/seeing-unwanted-text-enhance-ads/

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same text-enhance issue. It was installed on Chrome under the extension Premium-play codec c. Deleting the ext got rid of the adware.

Answer (score 0):

To de-install this **trojan horse**, follow these steps:

De-install the following program(s) (go to the 'Add/Remove' section in the Control Panel):

--Pando media enhancer 
--I Want This!

2) Apps/extensions for Chrome
*To remove extensions, type chrome://extensions into the omnibox/address bar
*To remove apps, go to the New Tab page > Apps panel > right click app you want to remove

--Premiumplay Codec-C (extension)
--Yontoo Layers (extension?) 
--Rewards Gaming (app)

For Internet Explorer, disable the same extension(s).

I hope this helped banish this software from the internet.

Best regards and good luck!

Answer (score 0):

When you get a pop-up, click on the name of the company that conducts the ads and you will go to their corporate site that has a disable link and it will effectively disable these links in any page that the company conducts business. Close and reopen browser and you will no longer see double line ads from that company anywhere on the internet. If you clear your cookies you will have to repeat this step, However, this is an easy way to stop the ads without corrupting your OS or browser. If you have to hack code and you don't know what you are doing you can damage a program or your computer beyond repair...If you know what you are doing then go forth and hack away.